# Agregar a un array datos obtenidos por AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, array

Al hacer clic, me trae los datos del producto y los puedo imprimir en consola.

Lo que quiero saber, es cómo hacer que, cada vez que hago clic, se agreguen los datos a un array, para que se vaya llenando una tabla y, por ejemplo, al hacer 2 o más clics el mismo producto (botón del card), en la tabla, solo cambie el campo "cantidad" y no se que repita el producto.

```
$('body').on('click touch', '#prducto .botoncardproducto', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace("boton-card-", "");
        $.post('../php/buscar.php', { id }, function(response) {
            const datos = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(datos.id + " | " + datos.precio + " | " + datos.img + " | " + datos.nombre);
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado, porque ni siquiera has definido el array.

Comment: Es lo que estoy preguntando, como hago para definir el array y llenarlo.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si creas un array solo estará visible durante la ejecución en la misma página y se perderá al recargar o cambiar de página. Tal vez debas usar cookies, localStorage o, incluso, AJAX para enviarlo al servidor y manejarlo en base de datos o variables de sesión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te puedo dar una idea de cómo hacerlo ya que falta cómo luce la respuesta por parte del servidor y cómo manejas la cantidad, por lo tanto no puedo responderte de manera certera. Voy a asumir que la respuesta es así:

```
{id: 'xxxx', precio: 'xxxx', img: 'xxxx', nombre: 'xxxx'}
```

y que la cantidad la manejas en el objeto.

Define un array de productos:

```
let productosArray;
```

Cuando selecciones un producto verifica si ya existe en el array:

```
let index = productosArray.findIndex(d=>d.id === datos.id)
```

ahora, si existe, le aumentas en 1 la cantidad:

```
productosArray[index].cantidad += 1;
```

Y si no existe, le añades la cantidad 1 y lo agregas al array:

```
datos.cantidad = 1;
productosArray.push(datos);
```

El código completo luciría algo así:

```
var productosArray; // Arriba para que la variable sea global 

$('body').on('click touch', '#prducto .botoncardproducto', function(e) {

        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace("boton-card-", "");

        $.post('../php/buscar.php', { id }, function(response) {

            let datos = JSON.parse(response);
            let index = productosArray.findIndex(d=>d.id === datos.id)

            if(index >= 0){
               
                productosArray[index].cantidad += 1;

            } else{

                datos.cantidad = 1;
                productosArray.push(datos);

            }

        })
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

Y por ultimo usas la variable `productosArray` para llenar la tabla.

No lo tomes como una respuesta a tu pregunta (ya que por falta de información no puedo responderla bien), míralo más como una idea de cómo puedes resolver el problema